# Translating verilog behavioral level to register transfer level

Tags: verilog

Im new to verilog and having troubling translating behavioral level code to register transfer level if any one can help me translate this and explain the difference it would be greatly appreciated. My code seems to be working but i cant seem to find any help as to write it in register transfer level.

```
   module combinational_mult(product,multiplier,multiplicand);
       input [31:0]  multiplier, 
       input [63:0] multiplicand;
       output        product;
     
       reg [63:0]    product;
       reg           c;
       reg [63:0]    m;  
       integer       i;
     
       always @( multiplier or multiplicand )
         begin
    //initialize
            product[63:32] = 32'd0;
            product[31:0] = multiplier;
            m = multiplicand;
            c = 1'd0;
     
          
    //add,shift algorithm  for unsigned multiplication.        
    //following the notes.
             for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)
               begin
                   if(product[0]) {c,product[63:32]} = product[31:16] + m ;
                     product[63:0] = {c,product[63:1]};
                        c = 0;
           
     
     
      end    
    endmodule

    module testbench;
     reg [31:0] multiplier;
     reg [63:0] multiplicand;

    initial begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars;

      #10ns;
      multiplier   = 16'b1101_1001_1101_1001;
      multiplicand = 16'b0110_1010_1101_1000;

      #50ns;
      multiplier   = 16'b0;
      multiplicand = 16'b0;

      $finish;
    end

    combinational_mult dut ( product, multiplier, multiplicand);
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

As your design is purely combinational, there isnt really a RTL (register transfer level) description that makes much sense or is that meaningful.

When describing digital sequential logic at an RTL level from Verilog; you need to have an idea of the registers (data holding) elements in your system and what affects the value each of these registers takes on. In your case, as there are not registers, you dont really have any RTL there, just a multiplier which is a valid unit in RTL. You can go deeper and describe your multipler in terms of how the various adders in your system are hooked up, but thats a bit lower than what Id call RTL.

A quick google search yields a text book chapter on RTL: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp13/cse140-a/lectures/rtl.pdf